# protect_from_forgery with: :exception rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, localhost

I am working on a new rails project and having some trouble right off the bat with this error  in my localhost development environment:

```
protect_from_forgery with: :exception
```

My application helper file:

```
 class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
end
```

Any ideas how I can circumvent and/or resolve this error?

A thing to note, this is happening on

```
http://localhost:3000/pages/home
```

but not

http://localhost:3000

This is my application trace:

```
artwe@DESKTOP-9MER9I4 /c/sites/cookies (master)
$ rails --trace
** Invoke default (first_time)
** Invoke test (first_time)
** Execute test
** Execute default
Run options: --seed 1992

# Running:

E

Error:
PagesControllerTest#test_should_get_home:
AbstractController::Helpers::MissingHelperError: Missing helper file helpers/c:/sites/cookies/app/helpers/application_helper.rb_helper.rb
    app/controllers/application_controller.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    app/controllers/pages_controller.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    test/controllers/pages_controller_test.rb:5:in `block in <class:PagesControllerTest>'


bin/rails test test/controllers/pages_controller_test.rb:4



Finished in 1.552152s, 0.6443 runs/s, 0.0000 assertions/s.
1 runs, 0 assertions, 0 failures, 1 errors, 0 skips
```

Comment: Can you post the error stack trace?

Comment: `skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token` add this line next to your `protect_from_forgery with: :exception`

Comment: @Gabbar if he does that, what is the point of keeping protect_from_forgery then ...

First, what is your error ?
You say that it occurs on http://localhost:3000/pages/home
 but forgery check should only occur on action other than GET and you url kind a look like a GET request to me.

Answer (score 1):

protect_from_forgery is rails feature to protect unauthorized attacks by other users. So, if you are getting this error means you are trying to authenticate on that page.
You can add `skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token` to skip it.

Comment: Thx I'll give this a go tonight

Comment: I am now getting this error: Missing helper file helpers/c:/sites/cookies/app/helpers/application_helper.rb_helper.rb